# Gson Parser accepting toString Representation instead of Json syntax

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

While debugging a piece of code which deserialized string to Object,  i realised the JSON Parsing there is working with toString representation rather than json representation of the object.

Pojo:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class Pojo {

    int a;
    String b;
}
```

Parse Logic:

```
Gson gsonInstance =
        new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .create();
String json2 = "{a=5, b=field}";
Pojo obj = gsonInstance.fromJson(json2, Pojo.class);

System.out.println(obj);
```

This started breaking when i added fields containing ":" to the Pojo. Like dates.

Two questions around this :
1)How is Gson even supporting this? I couldn't find any doc. of the same.
2)How do I handle the date related issue i mentioned earlier with this toString kind of implementation? I tried escaping the string for Java, that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Gson, it is actually documented but the documentation is a bit buried. Refer: [Gson.java](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java). The JSON deserialization final call is

`public <T> T fromJson(JsonReader reader, Type typeOfT) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException`

In the body of the code, refer:

```
reader.setLenient(true);
```

Now refer to [JsonReader.java](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.java)

```
 public final void setLenient(boolean lenient)
```

The javadoc on the method states as follows:

> /**
>      * Configure this parser to be liberal in what it accepts. By default,
>      * this parser is strict and only accepts JSON as specified by RFC 4627. Setting the
>      * parser to lenient causes it to ignore the following syntax errors:
>      *
>      *
>
>   *
> - Streams that start with the non-execute
>        *       prefix, `")]}'\n"`.
>        *
>
>   Streams that include multiple top-level values. With strict parsing,
>        *       each stream must contain exactly one top-level value.
>        *
>
>   Top-level values of any type. With strict parsing, the top-level
>        *       value must be an object or an array.
>        *
>
>   Numbers may be {@link Double#isNaN() NaNs} or {@link
>        *       Double#isInfinite() infinities}.
>        *
>
>   End of line comments starting with {@code //} or {@code #} and
>        *       ending with a newline character.
>        *
>
>   C-style comments starting with {@code /*} and ending with
>        *       {@code *}{@code /}. Such comments may not be nested.
>        *
>
>   Names that are unquoted or {@code 'single quoted'}.
>        *
>
>   Strings that are unquoted or {@code 'single quoted'}.
>        *
>
>   Array elements separated by {@code ;} instead of {@code ,}.
>        *
>
>   Unnecessary array separators. These are interpreted as if null
>        *       was the omitted value.
>        *
>
>   Names and values separated by {@code =} or {@code =>} instead of
>        *       {@code :}.
>        *
>
>   Name/value pairs separated by {@code ;} instead of {@code ,}.
>        *
>
> */

The above is the reason why Gson parses your string and deserializes the same.

The above would not work if your name/value (unquoted) have any ':', reason being Gson would interpret (in your case)as name=[value or anotherName???]:value (Gson is not that lenient).

Use proper valid JSON and de-serialize.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Gson with an enabled complex map key serialization.

```
new Gson().newBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
```

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()